# Those damned "Screws" in the "Das Boot"

Tags: meaning, terminology

In the [emergency dive scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVBPGZEVRH0) one seaman is carrying a box with eggs which also has the convenient inscription "Vorsicht Eier!" (Careful, eggs !). On 0:14/0:15 he says on German: "Wahrschau ! Eier !" which means "Caution, eggs !" because "Wahrschau!" is a German warning in seaman's language.

Now the English translation is "Screws, eggs" on 0:15.

Screws ? Neither the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screw?q=screws) nor Seaman's language dictionaries were able to help out. Is "Screws" an existing expression and if not, how on earth did the translator come to the conclusion to use "Screws" ?

Comment: You have to ask the translator. Not here.

Comment: So "Screws" has no meaning ?

Comment: Try moving your question to  http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could someone be ordering the [screw-shaped impellers](http://hydratechpumps.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/centrifugal-screw-pump.jpg) on the submarine to be activated to perform the dive?

Comment: @ab2 Linguistics is about the structure of a language, not the meaning of specific words. ELL is also not correct because it is for learners of English and we have a specific term which is (?) lingo. Given that the meaning *does not occur in dictionaries* and is therefore not a translation request, it is a valid question. At least it was a valid question some time ago...

Comment: @Thorsten S Nevertheless, if you don't get any response here,  try it out on Linguistics, where you will find people who are fluent in English, German, German WWII slang and translation goofs.  Note that you should not post two identical questions on two sites.

Comment: @Rathony: It is "Screw*s*", not "Screw". Apart from the plural of "Screw" its usage seems to imply a noun (like a slang impression). "Screws eggs" using both plural seems senseless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Linguistics Exchange and is unanswerable here at EL&U.

Comment: @ThorstenS. That's why I said it was my best guess. Anyway, if you ask about all the mistranslated subtitles in the world, how many questions do you think you can ask on this site? I believe it would be more than the world's population.

Comment: Typo for "crew's eggs" ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. Does "Warsaw" in German actually mean the same as Vorscicht ?

Comment: @Gandalf [Yes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahrschau). "In der Schifffahrt wird Wahrschau! bis heute als Warnruf benutzt, und leitet sich wahrscheinlich von einer Fehlinterpretation des englischen Satzes "Watch out!" ab".(In shipping "Wahrschau!" is still used as warning and its roots seems to be a misinterpretation of the english sentence. "Watch out" ).

Comment: @Graffito Now that's an interesting idea....

Comment: @ThorstenS. Gotcha. That's like in Mexican Spanish they use "Guachiman" for watchman.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no such term in normal English; whether was a mistranslation, a mishearing or something else might fit on Movies.SE.

Comment: So maybe "Screws" is some weird misinterpretation of "Excuse [me]" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My German is far from native, but here goes...

**Schraube means 'screw'**, in several ways. For example as the [simple machine](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedische_Schraube), as in the [*metal threaded fastener*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schraube). Just like in English, really. Though I believe German has a few more variations. You can see how *"(war) schrau, eier*" can be interpreted as *"(something) screw, eggs"*.

Tangentially; 'Wahrschau' seems like a weird verbal cue, and I'm thinking it's just weirdly translated to German. It sounds a lot like Warschau (Warsaw, Poland), and it's like saying *"warning shout!"* in English, instead of *"look out!"*.

Perhaps it really is part of submarine lingo, but my guess is they're saying *"Pass auf, eier"* and it was just misheard or something.

[edit] Apparently, *"warschrau"* is an actual term, and it (probably) originates from mishearing the English "watch out".[/edit]

All in all, this seems a typical case of getting lost in translations.

Comment: Please see the conversation between Thorstens S and myself for the use of "Warschau!"